# Problem with my addEventListner returning null in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events

Hey was wondering if anyone would be able to help me figure out where I went wrong in this code. I am very new to coding so sorry if it is a little wonky. Very open to any feedback! I am trying to make a password generator that prompts you asking how many characters in total and which characters to include.

The function worked when I logged it but adding it to the button to generate when you click it kinda went a little downhill.

Also not as important but in my prompting I can't figure out how to get the else statement to restart the process if they put a number outside the parameters.

```
var spec = '!@$%^&*()_+';
var low = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var num = '0123456789';
var upp = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
```

```
var charLength = prompt("How many characters between 8 - 128?");

if (charLength >= 8, charLength <= 128) {
 var lowChar = confirm("Include lowercase letters?");
 var upChar = confirm("Include uppercase letters?");
 var specChar = confirm("Include special characters?");
 var numChar = confirm("Include numbers?");
}

else {
    var charLength = prompt("How many characters between 8 - 128?");
};
```

```
var passwords = document.getElementById("password");
var generate = document.getElementById("btnGen");
var copy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");

generate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var characters = '';
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';

    passwords.value = password(charLength.value, characters)
});


function password(l, characters){
    var pwd = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
    pwd += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return pwd;
}
```

Thank You!

Comment: `character` and `characters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in eventListener function
Please check the new code. you misspelled 'var character' instead of 'var characters'.
And when calling 'password' function first parameter have to be charLength instead of charLength.value.

```
generate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var characters = ''; /* var character = ''; */
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';
    passwords.value = password(charLength /*charLength.value*/, characters)
});
```

```js
var spec = '!@$%^&*()_+';
var low = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
var num = '0123456789';
var upp = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var charLength = prompt("How many characters between 8 - 128?");

if (charLength >= 8, charLength <= 128) {
 var lowChar = confirm("Include lowercase letters?");
 var upChar = confirm("Include uppercase letters?");
 var specChar = confirm("Include special characters?");
 var numChar = confirm("Include numbers?");
}

else {
    var charLength = prompt("How many characters between 8 - 128?");
};
var passwords = document.getElementById("password");
var generate = document.getElementById("btnGen");
var copy = document.getElementById("btnCopy");

generate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var characters = '';
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';
    passwords.value = password(charLength, characters)
});


function password(l, characters){
    var pwd = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < l; i++){
    pwd += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length))
    }
    return pwd;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="password"/>

<div>


<span id="btnGen">Generate</span>
<span id="btnCopy">Copy</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah that was a miss-type on here in my file it is characters. I did try the charLength instead and it's still giving me 'Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' in the console

Comment: Then it's the issue related to the html dom element. generate is not obtained properly. I updated the answer with full code.

Comment: Idk why but running the snippet on here works but when I put it into a html file and link it to a separate javascript file it won't work it gives the same thing even tried putting them in the same html file just putting the javascript into the script tag. Thank you for making the javascript actually work here at least.

Comment: If you are putting javascript in the head section before the elements get loaded, then it will give an error because it will try to find elements that are not loaded yet. Try to put the javascript below the all elements. If you are using jquery all script should be go inside jQuery(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 0):

First, the function. Maybe try having the function be predefined? Much simpler. For example, instead of:

```
generate.addEventListener("click", function(){
    var character = '';
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';

    passwords.value = password(charLength.value, characters)
});
```

try

```
function onClick() {
    var character = '';
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';
    passwords.value = password(charLength.value, characters)
}
generate.addEventListener("click", onClick);
```

also, there is usually a third argument. In your case, use `false`. For example:

```
function onClick() {
    var character = '';
    lowChar ? characters += low : '';
    upChar ? characters += upp : '';
    specChar ? characters += spec : '';
    numChar ? characters += num : '';
    passwords.value = password(charLength.value, characters)
}
generate.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
```

Should work?

Comment: Tried it and it is still giving me Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null in the console.